# data binding is not happening in angular js application

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am not able to do data binding using angularJS application.

The following is the HTML template file as databinding.html and Javascript file as invoice.js.

It is priting {{ fname }} {{ lname }} besides John Doe.

```
<!DOCTYPE html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="InvoiceController">
        First Name :<input type="text" ng-model='fname' /><br />
        Last Name:<input type="text" ng-model='lname' /><br />
        {{ fname }} {{ lname }}
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="invoice.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

angular.module('myApp', []).controller('InvoiceController', ['$scope', 
function($scope) {
    $scope.fname = 'John';
    $scope.lname = 'Doe';
}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

The order of the scripts is wrong. The controller logic won't work because it doesn't know what angular is yet.

Change this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="invoice.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
```

to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>        
<script type="text/javascript" src="invoice.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thant you @Harshil Shah. Does it mean that when we put reference of angular.min.js below to reference of invoice.js, we give higher priority to the invoice.js compare to angular.min.js. That is why it is not giving output as we want to expect ?

Comment: @Avdheshsharma You have to put 'angular.min.js' FIRST and everything else like angular controllers, services etc. AFTER or BELOW  'angular.min.js' script.